# BotFramework - Error 401 - Unauthorized - Works on Emulator with AppId and Secret but doesn't work in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, unauthorized

I have a bot developed with BotFramework V3 in C# (current Microsoft.Bot.Builder version is 3.20.1).

I can successfully run it on Bot Emulator (providing the credentials at connection).

My web.config has the corrects MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword.

It is also saving state in Azure Cosmos DB.
I have tried recreate key with no success.
The endpoint is https.

On Azure environment, I can't run through Web Chat Test. 
It always results in Error 401 - Unauthorized. The message is:
There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized

I appreciate your help.

Tks

Comment: Are your appId and Password in the Configuration settings on Azure?

Comment: Yes, it is all setted. Both in Web.config and in azure.

Comment: Does it work in any channel?

Comment: No. I tried with webchat and facebook and the problem is the same.

The problem is the Azure connecting to it.

As a test, I deployed it to a server in the web and I could connect normally using Simulator.